# Visual Basic Script Excel MSXML2 GetRequest

Tags: excel, vba, request

I am trying to send an request and receive whole page source. Unfortunately i am getting only part of response. Is there any way to split response because i am think that is to huge to being handled by excel.

```
Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
objHTTP.Open "GET", strUrl, False
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
objHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
objHTTP.send ""
```

Comment: What makes you think you are getting part? You also don't need `""` after `send`. Also, see this re content-type and how to use `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type`

Comment: Request obtained by Postman is much longer. Request in excel ends suddenly